# Probability inequality implication

Tags: probability, probability-inequalities

Let $X$ and $Y$ be independent random variables, $A(X,Y)$ and $B(X)$ predicates with values true or false, and $Z$ a non-random variable taking values in the set of outcomes of $X$. Let $\delta\in(0,1)$ fixed. Suppose we know the following:

$P_Y[\forall Z, A(Z,Y) \Rightarrow B(Z)] > 1-\delta$.

Can we say that $P_X[A(X,Y)] \le P_X[B(X)]$ with probability $1-\delta$ with respect to the random draws of $Y$?

I know that from $A(X,Y)\Rightarrow B(X)$ it follows that $P_X[A(X,Y)]\le P[B(X)]$, but does this implication still hold with high probability w.r.t. Y?

Comment: This cannot be answered unless you define your terms!

Comment: @kjetil is right, because the usual mathematical meaning of your first probability does not appear to be what you want.  You have told us that $X$ is a (presumably *particular*) random variable, so quantifying over all such $X$ as stated in "$\forall X$" just makes no sense.